# jQuery.append, type input, and Windows Store App (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: jquery, winjs, windows-store-apps, jsrender

I have this Window Store App where I'd like to add some markup dynamically, and my problem can be boiled down to this:

Working

```
$('.some-element').append('<input type="radio"><label>Test</label>');
```

Not working

```
$('.some-element').append('<input type="radio" name="test"><label>Test</label>);
```

Visual Studio tells me that:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content. A script
>   attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified
>   dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML
>   property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception.
>   Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly
>   create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.

And points to a line in jQuery's append implementation:

```
append: function() {
        return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 ) {
                this.appendChild( elem ); // Here!
            }
        });
    }
```

Does anyone know if theres a way around this? (I need jQuery because I want to use JsRender as my templating engine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting the host enforcement security feature. The Win8 HTML host doesn't like it when you're creating elements from strings; in this case, specifically it doesn't like it when you put the name="" attribute on input elements. Could you set the id instead of the name?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465388.aspx for details on what's considered safe.

The error message actually gave you two options to work around the error:

1. use toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content
2. explicitly create elements and attributes

Using toStaticHTML would look like this:

```
    $('.some-element').append(toStaticHTML('<input type="radio" name="test"><label>Test</label>'));
```

But that will result in the HTML that gets created potentially looking different from the string you passed in; toStaticHTML will strip out elements and attributes that are considered unsafe.

The second option is to use the DOM APIs directly rather than jQuery to create the elements in question, you've already said that this is a no-go.

There is a third option, although it might not let you through the store verification process:

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {
    $('.some-element').append('<input type="radio" name="test"><label>Test</label>');
});
```

This will temporarily disable the unsafe html checks. ***DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS YOU'VE DONE A SECURITY ANALYSIS***. In particular, do NOT take a string you got from XHR and use it to create DOM, that's an invitation to getting your app, and your user's machine, pwnd.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The main problem in my case is that I would like to use JsRender for templating, and that uses jQuery. So I am not using jQuery myself "directly", so toStaticHTML isn't really an option. I could use the WinJS built-in templating, but that just kind of defies the point of being able to use your regular web tech stack for Windows Store Apps (I think) - but I guess I'm stuck with that or just typing the markup manually. Again, thank your for your reply, it was very usefull

Comment: There are a couple more options for you and you can still keep using JsRender, although I'm guessing here since I don't know JsRender. First, edit your rendering templates so that the things that are considered unsafe aren't included. The other would be to encapsulate the call to JsRender in the execUnsafeLocalFunction method - that turns off the safety check for the duration of that call stack. Although if JsRender does template rendering later (knockout.js has this issue when updating from binding) you won't be able to use execUnsafeLocalFunction without editing the source.

Comment: Well I don't really know which things are considered unsafe (so what's the next problem I'll run into?), and in my particular case the "name" attribute is on a radio button because I need a radio group. If I can't use that, I have to program functionality given by the browser myself (which I'm not really interested in).

Comment: Did you follow the link I put the the answer? That's the exact list of what's considered safe/unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe(divName, '<input type="radio"><label>Test</label>');
```